# Can I define multiple ColorStateLists in a single XML file?

Tags: android, android-resources

In my app I have a lot of controls that should change their text color when changing drawable state. Android provides a way to do it - color state lists. For each color state list I have to create a separate XML file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="#398ede" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="#808080"/>
</selector>
```

Is there any way to avoid creating a separate file for each color state list and define them all in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You must have found the answer by now, but for the sake of those who come to this link again, here's how we do it.

If you have a resource file defining multiple colors like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="xBlack">#FF000000</color>
<color name="xYellow">#FFFFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

You need to put this file under values (and not in colors)
To access the values you need to use:

```
dummy_button_id.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.xBlack));
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but only with "simple" colors, not state lists. If you try to define multiple color state lists like this you'll end up with an AAPT error. I tried this before asking this question :)

Comment: Did you find a way to that?